# How to duplicate rows if an entry has 2 or more values in a given column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have this dataframe:

```
   A = ['qwe','rty','uio']
   B = ['asd','fgh','jkl/zxc']
   df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 
                       'B': B})
   df
```

which outputs to:

```
    A   B
0   qwe asd
1   rty fgh
2   uio jkl/zxc
```

I want to be able to transform it to this:

```
    A   B
0   qwe asd
1   rty fgh
2   uio jkl
3   uio zxc
```

I'm new to python and I can't find anything to achieve this

Comment: did your query solved?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 1):

use `assign()` + `str.split()` + `explode()`:

```
df=df.assign(B=df['B'].str.split('/')).explode('B',ignore_index=True)
```

output of `df`:

```
     A      B
0   qwe     asd
1   rty     fgh
2   uio     jkl
3   uio     zxc
```